# How to remove top shadow to tab layout in android

Tags: java, android

**Hi i need add shadow under my tab layout and remove top of the tablayout **

**This is My Tab layout**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9YiA.png)

**My Activity xml :-**

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/header_text_color"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
    app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
    app:tabRippleColor="@color/transparent" />

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/banner_container"
    android:layout_below="@id/tablayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove properties

```html
android:elevation="2dp"


<!-- Other Wise edits this property -->

android:elevation="0dp"
```

Comment: only remove top shadow tablayout not all